# Как правильно указать путь к jsp?

Tags: java, servlet, jetty

[image: Код]

Пишу на Jetty. Структура папок на фото. Как правильно вызвать jsp из сервлета? Таким образом кидает  java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: Микроскоп прилагайте к скриншоту, а то так не интересно.

Comment: Не силен в работе с jetty, но разве не должно быть аннотаций самого сервлете или файла конфигураций?

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но для веб проектов jsp хранятся в resources/WEB-INF, как минимум обычно так IDE делают

Comment: да и вроде же как еще файл web.xml должен присутствовать

Comment: Он описывается при создании сервера. web.xml нет. Все настраивается с помощью методов Jetty